# clarifications about ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through some lecture notes and just wanted to check a few minor things in order to avoid confusion later on.

(1) Author defines an R-minimal element of Y as an a s/t there is no b≠a with bRa.  Author then claims that the Foundation states that, for every set, x, x has a ϵ-minimal element.  But isn't this incorrect unless the caveat that b≠a is removed?

(2) Author says that if (L, ≤) is a well-order, and A ⊆ L, then min(A) exists -- where min(A) is not just ≤-minimal, but is also "below" all b≠min(A).  This is because ≤ is linear, correct?

(3) Author defines a proper initial segment of a well order (L, ≤) as pred(L,x)={yϵL : x < y}, for some x in L.  But, strictly speaking, should the initial segment include an order -- namely, the restriction of < to x?

Comment: (1) Every set? Not every **nonempty** set? If $x$ is empty it can't have any element, let alone an $\in$-minimal element.

Comment: Author didn't write that, but, yes, that must have been what was intended.

Comment: (2) Again, must assume $A$ is nonempty.

Comment: Yes-- good eye!

Comment: Apart from the author's failure to state the necessary assumption that $x$ is nonempty, why do you think (1) is wrong? It looks OK to me. Can you give an example showing what goes wrong?

Comment: (2): Yes, that's because $\le$ is linear. (3) You mean $pred(L,x) = \{y\in L\mid y<x\}$ not $x<y$. Yes, the order is intended to be $\le_L$ restricted to the initial segment. The author doesn't explicitly display it in order to to reduce clutter and fuss, and because it's hopefully understood.

Comment: Thanks, Brian!  A couple of follow-ups.  On (2), my question was the following.  pred(L,x) = {y ϵ L : x < y} is just a set, not an ordered pair.  But, strictly speaking, shouldn't the initial segment of a well-order be an ordered pair, just as a well-order is?  On (1), bracketing the issue of emptiness, my worry was that, if we qualify that b≠a, then Foundation no longer rules out sets that contain themselves, right?

Comment: (Brian -- sorry, I misread your comment on (2).  Thanks, you answered that question, though I still wonder about (3).  I assume that what's going on is that the definition of well-foundedness is being given for a well-order based on a partial order.  In the case of a well-order based on a strict order, as with ∈, then one may indeed drop the caveat b≠a.  But I'd be grateful if you'd let me know if that's incorrect.)